# How to have both validation with type inference and authentication middleware in Express routes

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, middleware

I don't understand how types are inferred in `Express` routes through multiple middlewares.

I'm using the middleware package `express-zod-safe` to do some validation with `zod`, but note that the problem was the same with anonther middleware such as `zod-express-middleware`.

I have an `auth` middleware, which I would prefer to use first to not leak any information to unauthorized, but I have to first `validate` so that the typing is correctly infered:

```
import express from "express";
import validate from "express-zod-safe";
import { z } from "zod";

const app = express();

export function checkAuth<
  T extends express.Request,
  U extends express.Response,
  V extends express.NextFunction
>() {
  return (req: T, res: U, next: V) => {
    next();
  };
}

const schema = z.object({ id: z.coerce.number().min(0) });

app.get(
  "/api/product/:id",
  validate({ params: schema }), // This line should be after checkAuth
  checkAuth(),
  (req, res) => {
    req.params.test; // The Typescript server only rightfully complains when I validate first
    res.send("Here's a product");
  }
);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server running on port 3000"));
```

Edit: I plan to have other `routes` with different `params`, I want this type to be `inferred` by the Typescript server and the `checkAuth` function to be totally `generic`

Edit 2: I managed to put `checkAuth` first by putting `any` for the request type, but I lose the `Request` typing within it. How can I "merge" both types ?

```
export function checkAuth() {
  return (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    next();
  };
}
```

Edit 3: Okay I now have typing working correctly for both function using `never`:

```
export function checkAuth() {
  return (req: express.Request<never>, res: any, next: any) => {
    const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    next();
  };
}
```

But I don't understand exactly why, this seems postpone type inference to the next function, while `any` eats up all following typing. Is this how it's supposed to work ? Does anyone have a good guide to typing in Typescript ?

Answer (score 0):

In `checkAuth` function you can specify the types for req like so,

```js
export function checkAuth<
  T extends express.Request,
  U extends express.Response,
  V extends express.NextFunction
>() {
  return (req: T & { params: { id: number } }, res: U, next: V) => {
    // Now, TypeScript knows about the "id" property in params
    req.params.id;
    next();
  };
}
```

Comment: I plan to have other routes with different params, I want this type to be inferred by the Typescript server and the checkAuth function to be totally generic.

Comment: does `T & YOUR_GENERIC` will work?

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you elaborate ?

Comment: you said 'checkAuth function to be totally generic.' you can infer generic using `T & generic`

Comment: In my shown exemple, T is already the generic type, so I think your misunderstood my question

Comment: have you tried this `checkAuth<{ id: number }>()`  where T extends Record instead of express.Request?